# How to display a vuetify's v-progress-linear on the top of page when router is changing in vue2?

Tags: vue.js, progress-bar, vuetify.js, vue-router

How can I give my page a great process bar on the top when I changed the route?
this is the vuetify's process-linear:

```
 <v-progress-linear
      indeterminate
      color="yellow darken-2"
    ></v-progress-linear>
```

But How can I make them work together?
infomation:

- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-linear/#indeterminate

Comment: did you try to use `<v-app-bar>` and `<v-content>` together? put your `<v-progress-linear>` in `<v-app-bar>` and `<router-link>` in  `<v-content>`

Answer (score 1):

put your loader in App.vue and wrap it in

```
<router-view></router-view>
<PageLoader :mode="page_loading"> </PageLoader>
```

Comment: pleace tell me what is a PageLoader?is it your self-build component?

Comment: yes, and it should be inside of v-app component .